# Convert UIView frames to self.view coordinate space

Tags: swift

Because my frames are in stackviews, my UI elements are returning their frame in the superview coordinate system (that is, the stackview)

I want to return them in the self.view coordinate space.

Ho

```
    print ("untf frame",self.view.convert(usernameTextField.frame, to: self.view ) )
    print ("pwtf frame",self.view.convert(passwordTextField.frame, to: self.view ) )
```

both return the same values.

Of course I can see that passwordTextField is 50 down from username.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong

```
print ("untf frame",self.view.convert(usernameTextField.frame, to: self.view ) )
print ("pwtf frame",self.view.convert(passwordTextField.frame, to: self.view ) )
```

Your `usernameTextField` and  `passwordTextField` is subview of stackview so you need to convert it **to** `self.view`
Use like this

```
print ("untf frame",self.stackview.convert(usernameTextField.frame, to: self.view ) )
print ("pwtf frame",self.stackview.convert(passwordTextField.frame, to: self.view ) )
```